# Override column names of embedded id

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonId id;

    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @MapsId("a_phoneNumberId")
    @ManyToOne
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @MapsId("b_addressId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;
    ...
```

with embedded id:

```java
@Embeddable
public class PersonId implements Serializable {

    private int a_phoneNumberId;
    private int b_addressId;
    ...
```

Note: `a_` and `b_` prefixes are used to order columns in primary key.

Everything works as expected and hibernate generates a table with columns: `phoneNumber_id` and `address_id`.

Is it possible to rename those columns, as I want to have a snake_case name - `phone_number_id`?

So far I tried

- [`@AttributeOverride`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) annotation:

  ```java
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "person")
  public class Person {

      @EmbeddedId
      @AttributeOverrides({
              @AttributeOverride(name = "a_phoneNumberId", column = @Column(name = "phone_number_id"))
      })
      private PersonId id;
  ```
- @Column annotation for the id:

  ```java
  @Embeddable
  public class PersonId implements Serializable {

      @Column(name = "phone_number_id")
      private int a_phoneNumberId;
  ```

  but it changed nothing.

Comment: Is there any hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy set in your application? Because the default is to convert camel case to snake case

Comment: I think you may be wrong, the default one (`ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl`) sets the name of the column the same as the name of the fields. And no, I use the default naming strategy.